# Exception sometimes not caught using C++ / GCC / Linux

Tags: c++, exception, gcc, arm

Occasionally I encounter a piece of code where an exception is not caught. So far I have no idea what a possible reason can be.

As an example the piece of code below.

- The log message "initializing" is printed.
- Some log messages from module->Init() are printed
- module->init() throws an exception
- Log messages in the catch blocks are not printed

Application terminates

```
log::trace( "Initializing" );
try
{
   module->Init();
}
catch( const std::exception& e )
{
    log::error( "Error initializing module:{}", e.what());
}
catch( ... )
{
    log::error( "Unknown exception initializing module" );
}

dmesg:
[    9.557049] terminate called after throwing an instance of '
[    9.562655] std::runtime_error
[    9.565715] '
[    9.567350]   what(): 
followed by the error message passed to what() which was the generated  exception message in init.
```

- Exception handling works as expected in other parts of the same application.
- Exception is thrown from the main thread.
- Embedded ARM platform with build system. All libraries are compiled with the same compiler.
- Compiler used GCC 8.2.0

Is there anything I am not aware of, which might cause an exception not to be caught ?

Comment: Can `log::error` throw?

Comment: *"followed by error message passed to what()"*. That might indicate/hint origin of the exception.

Comment: Can some destructors throw (during unwinding)?

Comment: Please provide a complete, reproducible code example.

Comment: log::error can throw, but then I wouldn't expect the message generated with the original throw statement. (clarified in the code block that the error message in dmesg is the message from the original exception)

"Can some destructors throw (during unwinding)"
As far as I am aware there are no destructors involved (after the init call) which involve any code. (Except standard library containers / std::string which are used)

Comment: Does `log::error` call `std::terminate` or similar? Does replacing `module->Init()` by throw `std::runtime_error("test");` have similar result? is `log` your class, or from a lib one?

Comment: Can you run the code under a debugger?  You should be able to place a general breakpoint on `throw` calls (`catch throw` in gdb) which might provide a bit more info.

Comment: Is `module->Init()` declared `noexcept`?

Answer (score 1):

Actually overlooked something in the header file. The function was marked "noexcept" which actually caused a terminate when an exception was thrown.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that catch(...) catches division by zero errors and bad pointer errors in C++ in Windows. But in Linux, I'm out of luck. The program is going to crash. Nothing I can do about it. But it would be nice to know where the error was or maybe even display a stack trace like C# does.

I found that Linux sends a [signal](https://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/courses/moved.Building/signals.pdf) to the program just before Linux dumps it. I can catch that signal and display an error message. I tried escaping from the signal back to the main program with [setjmp](https://cplusplus.com/reference/csetjmp/setjmp/) and [longjmp](https://cplusplus.com/reference/csetjmp/longjmp/), but I have found that the program is gonna die and nothing can save it.

I wrote this project to demonstrate how to catch the error with the [signal](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/signal-handling-in-cpp/) command and display a stack trace where the error happened at.

https://notabug.org/RussellHankins/ShowErrorsInC-Linux